# Typing at symbol (shift+2) displays double quote (") and Typing at symbol (shift+') attherate (@) in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, keyboard

I am working with ubuntu16.04. While working with terminal i had seen that my keyboard keys typing different signs. For example

```
Typing at symbol (shift+2) displays double quote (") 
Typing at symbol (shift+') atTheRate (@) 
Typing at symbol (shift+3) Euro (£)
```

.

I restarted my system but still it's showing same.

Comment: Well it's not a question... I don't get where the problem is.

Comment: you are using an English keyboard lyout not a US keyboard layout. Change your local

Comment: Yes @ravery you are right. I already changed it and it works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accidentally I changed my system language preference from the top right corner of my screen in ubuntu.

[image]

and by switching it again on English(US) my issue resolved.